# breaks option and sum(h$density) in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to plot an histogram using R.
I decided to use the function hist() but I cannot understand why by changing the "breaks" option the sum of the density also changes.

In fact if I write

```
h <- hist(data, freq =F, breaks = "FD")
```

and then run

```
sum(h$density)
```

the result is 2 (same thing for breaks = "Scott"). While if I use

```
h <- hist(data, freq =F)
```

the result is 1 (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

Summing the density values only makes sense if your bins are one unit wide.  You want to sum the areas of the bars, which is the density value times the bin width.  Presumably your `FD` bins are half the width of the default bins.